# JMeter report 95% line

Tags: jmeter

We have a JMeter requirment to get the 95% line. JMeter by default displays only the 90% line. Is there a way I can get the 95% value using external plugins or using some option in JMeter itself

Muthiah

Comment: Use Aggregate Report

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write the results to an output file and import that file into excel then use PERCENTILE function to calculate your 95%.  PERCENTILE(data,9.5)

Comment: When you save the result file, make sure you have clicked on configure button and enabled save elapsed time.  Load it in excel and on this value you will be applying the percentile function to obtain 95% percentile.

Answer (score 8):

In version 2.13 of JMeter 95% and 99% lines were introduced and you can customize them. It was added to Aggregate Graph and Aggregate Report listeners.

More detailed release notes you can find under [changes](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html) and [changes history](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html)

Answer (score 6):

You can use our plugin which generates all percentiles: http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/RespTimePercentiles

Stephane

Comment: Link is broken. Closest I could find is https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RespTimesDistribution/

Answer (score 1):

Jmeter itself does not have an option for this.

You could export the results to a spreadsheet and use a formula to extrapolate the 95% line yourself.  I do this often to get weighted averages.

Comment: can you give me more info on how to export the results to a spreadsheet from JMeter

Comment: If I am not wrong to get a 95% line, I would need to be able to export the raw number that JMeter captures for each thread, when the thread was sent and when it received

Answer (score 1):

Use Jmeter 2.13 version, there you can get 95% column in aggregate report

Comment: If I use Aggregate Graph, I can see that there are columns like Median,90% line,etc. I know how to run it in interactive mode and in non-gui mode as well. But how to run it in non-gui mode so that Aggregate Graph is saved to file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use J-meter version >2.13. There you can get 95% column. You can modify them as well from "jmeter.properties" file. Look for below entries:-

aggregate_rpt_pct1=90

aggregate_rpt_pct2=95

aggregate_rpt_pct3=99